# How to get completely rid of shadow acne and erroneous self shadowing?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl, shadow

I'm doing Simple Shadow Mapping and have problems with handling shadow acne and erroneous self shadowing and just can't get rid of it.
I already tried adding a bias to the depth value and rendering back faces to the depth buffer, but it doesn't remove all artifacts.
I also have problems choosing the right bias which leads to Peter Panning.

[Here I have some screenshots.](https://picasaweb.google.com/107094611410670291743/ShadowMapping?authkey=Gv1sRgCJK0j92UxtufhwE#)

So my questions are:

1. Is there a robust (and easy) way to completely eliminate shadow acne and erroneous self shadowing?
2. How to choose the perfect bias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a technique called [variance shadow maps](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch08.html) which is subject to its own peculiar artifacts, but which is very good at eliminating shadow acne and erroneous self-shadowing.  It was designed as a nonlinear filter for shadow maps, to avoid jaggies due to low resolution.

Briefly, it estimates the variance of the depth map, and uses that to find a smooth, conservative estimate of shadowing vs. depth.  You need to be careful about buffer precision, as most implementations seem to evaluate the variance in ways that abuse their dynamic range.