# Opengl Shadow map for each entity?

Tags: opengl

So this is an theory problem. Let's say we have 2 objects

1. An box
2. The floor

The sun shinning vertically above. The box is directly above the floor by some good distance. Now I render the `Shadow map` with the box and floor together in the scene.

But when I sample this `Shadow map` individually inside the box and floor shader's the `box` and the `floor` are an complete mess with black and white strips running all over it.

But I discovered when I create 2 separate `Shadow maps`

1. Box map
2. Floor map

`Box map` contains no objects because I assumed that there are no object's above the box to cast Shadow on it

`Floor map` contains only the box as the box is above it and so it casts an Shadow on the floor

When I sample these 2 individual `Shadow maps` in each respective shader the results are correct.

So I was just wondering in the real world with objects moving all over the place how do we keep track of what object casts an `Shadow` on what?

Do we use separate `Shadow maps` for every object. Keeping track of what obejct is in front? Or do we use depth condition's in the shader's?

If the latter some theory or algorithm in the form of shader code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create one shadow map for each light source, and not for each object.

The artifacts you see are called selfshadowing, and are most likely because you render the front face of the objects for the shadow map and not the backfaces and that you do not add a small offset.

The trick with the backface only rendering will only work for closed objects with a volume, and not object like floor, there the only way is to use a slight offset.

That you create only one shadow map is not necessarly true, depending on the scene you might create multiple shadow maps for one light source, to be able to get detailed shadows for close objects. But that does not change the fact, that the shadow maps are per light source and not per object.

- [How to get completely rid of shadow acne and erroneous self shadowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539869/how-to-get-completely-rid-of-shadow-acne-and-erroneous-self-shadowing)
- [Basic shadow mapping artifacts using OpenGL and GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401223/basic-shadow-mapping-artifacts-using-opengl-and-glsl)
- [OpenGL shadow peter-panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671823/opengl-shadow-peter-panning)

Comment: Could always model the floor as a rectangular prism :)

Comment: Yup that explains everything Thank u